# Is there a standard way of fixing missing values in pandas index column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## The problem

I'm working with a data set, which has been given to me as a csv file with lines of the form `id,data`. I would like to work with this data in a pandas dataframe, with the id as the index.

Unfortunately, somewhere along the data pipeline, my csv files has a number of rows where the id's are missing. Fortunately, the rows of my data are not fully independent, so I can recreate the missing values: each row is linked to its predecessor, and I have access to an oracle which, when given an id, can give me all its data. This includes the id of its predecessor.

My question is therefore whether there's a simple way of filling in these missing values in my dataframe

## My Solution

I don't have much experience working with pandas, but after playing around for a bit I came up with the following approach. I start by reading the csv file into a dataframe without setting the index, so I end up with a RangeIndex. I then

1. Find the location of the rows with missing ids
2. Add 1 to the index to get the children of each row
3. Ask the oracle for the parents of each child
4. Merge the parents and children on the child id
5. Subtract one from the index again, and set the parent ids

In code:

```
children = df.loc[df[df['id'].isna()].index + 1, 'id']
parents = pd.Series({x.id: x.parent_id for x in ask_oracle(children)},
                    name='parent_id')

combined = pd.merge(children, parents, left_on='id', right_index=True)
combined.set_index(combined.index - 1, inplace=True)
df.loc[combined.index, 'id'] = combined['parent_id']
```

This works, but I'm 95% sure it's going to look like scary black magic in a few months time.

**In particular**, I'm unhappy with

- The way I get the location of the nan rows. Three lots of `df[` in one line is just too many
- The manual fiddling about with the indices I have to do to get the rows to match up.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a better way of doing things?

The format of the input data is fixed, as are the properties of the oracle, but if there's a smarter way of organising my dataframe, I'm more than happy to hear it.